# Error when trying to advice python-shell-send-string

Tags: python, advice, comint

I'm trying to write advice such that each time I eval a python snippet, it automatically output the exception time in the emacs python shell

```
(defun python-send-with-time-record (orig-func string &optional process msg)
  (let ((wrap (mapconcat #'identity
                         `("import time"
                           "_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()"
                           ,string
                           "print('(took: {elapsed:.2f} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))")
                         "\n")))
    (funcall orig-func wrap process msg)))
(advice-add 'python-shell-send-string :around #'python-send-with-time-record)
```

However, when I eval something like `(python-shell-send-string "print(123)")`, Emacs took me to the debugger

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size")
  window-live-p(#<window 7 on init-python.el>)
  window-normalize-window(#<window 7 on init-python.el> t)
  unrecord-window-buffer(#<window 7 on init-python.el> #<buffer  *temp file*>)
  replace-buffer-in-windows(#<buffer  *temp file*>)
  kill-buffer(#<buffer  *temp file*>)
  #[0 "\301\300!\205    �\302\300!\207" [#<buffer  *temp file*> buffer-name kill-buffer] 2]()
  python-shell--save-temp-file("import time\n_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()\nimport codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260vvw''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260vvw''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el''', 'exec'));\nprint('(took: {elapsed:.2f} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))")
  #[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[  ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)]("import time\n_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()\nimport codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260vvw''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260vvw''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el''', 'exec'));\nprint('(took: {elapsed:.2f} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))" #<process Python> nil)
  funcall(#[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[  ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)] "import time\n_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()\nimport codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260vvw''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260vvw''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el''', 'exec'));\nprint('(took: {elapsed:.2f} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))" #<process Python> nil)
  (let ((wrap (mapconcat (function identity) (cons "import time" (cons "_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()" (cons string (quote ...)))) "\n"))) (funcall orig-func wrap process msg))
  python-send-with-time-record(#[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[     ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)] "import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el''', 'exec'));" #<process Python>)
  apply(python-send-with-time-record #[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[   ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)] ("import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el''', 'exec'));" #<process Python>))
  python-shell-send-string("import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el''', 'exec'));" #<process Python>)
  python-shell-send-file("/Users/user/.emacs.d/init/init-python.el" #<process Python> "/var/folders/rp/fqsg67z15d18xs191qk3xyvw0000gn/T/py8260QPN" t)
  #[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[  ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)]("import time\n_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()\nprint(1223)\nprint(42324)\nprint('(took: {elapsed:.2f} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))" nil nil)
  funcall(#[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[  ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)] "import time\n_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()\nprint(1223)\nprint(42324)\nprint('(took: {elapsed:.2f} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))" nil nil)
  (let ((wrap (mapconcat (function identity) (cons "import time" (cons "_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()" (cons string (quote ...)))) "\n"))) (funcall orig-func wrap process msg))
  python-send-with-time-record(#[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[     ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)] "print(1223)\nprint(42324)")
  apply(python-send-with-time-record #[769 "\206�\300!\301\302\"\203\"�\303!\304 \206�\211\305\306$\266\202\2029�\307\"\210\301\310\"\2035�\301\311\"\2059�\307\312\"\207" [python-shell-get-process-or-error string-match ".\n+." python-shell--save-temp-file buffer-file-name python-shell-send-file t comint-send-string "\n\\'" "\n[   ].*\n?\\'" "\n"] 11 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.3-mac-6.8/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc" . 86989) (byte-code "\300\301!\302\303E\207" [read-string "Python command: " nil t] 3)] "print(1223)\nprint(42324)")
  python-shell-send-string("print(1223)\nprint(42324)")
  eval((python-shell-send-string "print(1223)\nprint(42324)") nil)
  eval-expression((python-shell-send-string "print(1223)\nprint(42324)") nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (python-shell-send-string "print(1223)\nprint(42324)") nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally notice that there are situations that `python-shell-send-string` and `python-shell-send-file` call each other.

The function `python-shell-send-string` use `\n` to identify whether it should send a string or a file. Adding a condition to avoid this situation should work. (NOT fully tested)

```
(defun python-send-with-time-record (orig-func string &optional process msg)
  (let* ((prefix (string-trim-left (substring string 0 (min (length string) 30))))
         (wrap (if (string-match "^\\(import codecs, os;__pyfile\\|from IPython.core.completerlib\\|def __PY[DOC\\|THON]\\)" string)
                   string
                 (mapconcat #'identity
                            `("import time"
                              "_EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME = time.time()"
                              ,(if (string-suffix-p ";" string) (substring string 0 -1) string)
                              "print(' (took: {elapsed:.2e} s)'.format(elapsed=time.time() - _EMACS_PYTHON_START_TIME))")
                            "\n"))))
    (funcall orig-func wrap process msg)))
(advice-add 'python-shell-send-string :around #'python-send-with-time-record)
```